# CALL instruction (syntax error), MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, pascal, inline-assembly, masm

**THE PROBLEM:** `Error 5: Syntax error` (pointed in comment in the code below)
Suppose, they should be replaced by equivalent instructions but I can't figure it out.  But why should I modify the code that was disassembled by AFD-Pro debugger? Thought, it just must be copied to replace it's analogue lines in *.PAS* code.

Have read *IA-32 Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual, Volume 1, chapter 6.3 "Calling Procedures Using Call and RET"* but still I don't understand why `CALL` points to `9721:0691` and why Turbo Pascal 7.0 compiler gives a *`syntax error`*.

**TOOLS:** Windows 7 OS, DosBOX 0.74, Turbo Pascal 7.0, AFD-Pro (in DosBOX).

The *.PAS* code:

```
Program ASMINLINE;
Var 
    i,m:integer;
    A:array [10..20] of integer;

Begin
    m:=1;
    i:=10;

    while i<=20 do begin
        A[i]:=3*i;
        m:=m+A[i];
        if m>100 then
            A[i]:=2*i;
            inc(i);
    end;

    ASM
    {for i:=10 to 20 do}
        MOV     i,000Ah
        JMP     @20
    @10:
        INC   i

    {write(A[i]:4);}
    @20:
        MOV     DI, 016Ch
        PUSH    DS
        PUSH    DI
        MOV     DI,i
        SHL     DI,1
        MOV     AX,[0042+DI]
        CWD
        PUSH    DX
        PUSH    AX
        MOV     AX,0004h
        PUSH    AX
        CALL    9721:0691
        {           ^ Error 5: Syntax error. }
        CALL    9721:05FE
        CALL    9721:0291
        CMP     i,0014h
        JNZ     @10
    END; {ASM}

    writeln;
End.
```

And here is the part of **.PRN** file I included into **.PAS** file.
I got it using AFD-Pro v1.0 (AdTec GmbH, 1987; Processor: 80286) debugger:

```
for i:=10 to 20 do
9716:0061 C70652000A00   MOV    [0052],000A
9716:0067 EB04           JMP    006D
9716:0069 FF065200       INC    W/[0052]

        write(A[i]:4);
9716:006D BF6C01         MOV    DI,016C
9716:0070 1E             PUSH   DS
9716:0071 57             PUSH   DI
9716:0072 8B3E5200       MOV    DI,[0052]
9716:0076 D1E7           SHL    DI,1
9716:0078 8B854200       MOV    AX,[0042+DI]
9716:007C 99             CWD
9716:007D 52             PUSH   DX
9716:007E 50             PUSH   AX
9716:007F B80400         MOV    AX,0004
9716:0082 50             PUSH   AX
9716:0083 9A91062197     CALL   9721:0691
9716:0088 9AFE052197     CALL   9721:05FE
9716:008D 9A91022197     CALL   9721:0291
9716:0092 833E520014     CMP    [0052],0014
9716:0097 75D0           JNZ    0069
```

Comment: Try call far ord call dword ptr .... ?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: A call to segment:offset is a FAR call, a call to just offset (relative to CS:) is near. Some assemblers need extra hints in the mnemonic for that (callf, call far etc).

Answer (score 0):

Many of the assemblers from that era did not like absolute segment addresses.  They preferred the use symbolic segments.

It would be written something like this (off the top of my head and it has been a long time since I have written old x86 assembler):

```
b123   segment  abs 0123H      ; declare segment at an absolute location

$  equ  4321h                  ; declare something at offset 0x4321

some_proc    proc   far
; body of function goes here
some_proc    endp

b123   ends                    ; end working in this segment


   .code

    call some_proc             ; should generate call to 123h:4321h
```

Comment: How to implement this solution if i have access to Code Segment only? As I understood, `.code` is the beginning of Code Segment, but where should (in which segment) `b123` be written?

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: `some_proc` is declared to be in segment `b123`, so the call instruction will be a `far` reference to `0123h:4321h`.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by replacing the memnonic ("CALL ...") by its corresponding byte- and word values.

Replace

```
CALL    9721:0691
```

by

```
DB 9Ah            { CALL FAR }
DW 0691h, 9721h   { 9721:0691 }
```

Don't forget the `h`-suffix!

Comment: I have to write it in the *Data segment*, right?
As I'm trying to use inline, how can I access the data segment from the middle of the program?

Comment: because if I replace `CALL   9721:0691` by `DB 9Ah` and `DW 0691h, 9721h`, I get a message: "16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem | `Turbo Pascal |  The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction. | CS:9721 IP:5efa OP:64 63 61 72 64`" as the program cashes.  P.S. quite new to assembler but do want to learn it, though it seems to be not so easy at first.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: No! "Replace" means really "replace". Write the two lines with "DB..." and "DW..." **instead** of the one line with "CALL...". But I'm in doubt about the sense of the action. The absolute address can change at the next compilation **and** at the next run.

Comment: When I replace exactly as you say, I get that message and the program crashes at `DB 9Ah`.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: Crash as expected. The far-calls are calls into the TP-runtime-library (`write(...)`) which addresses can change. In TP6 it is not possible to call that library from within inline-assembly.